# How to have multiple reducers trigger updates based on a common set of actions without repeating yourself?

Tags: redux

I would like many different redux actions in my app to all trigger common functionality in a specific reducer. I would like to avoid having to either repeat some flag in every action creator (like doThing: true) that the reducer looks for. I also don't want to have to have the reducer just look for every individual action that falls into this category, since that also requires someone to remember to do this every time they add a new action, like adding the flag.

I was thinking of dispatching a second action every time one of these actions is going to be dispatched. This would not be hard to do, but I'd rather not have 2 actions dispatched every time one thing happens. It seems like it would pollute the state history.

Is there a common way of solving this problem?

For more context to my specific problem, the specific feature is related to the API client my app uses to talk to our API. On every successful response, we'd like to do something in a reducer to update the state, and on every failed response, we'd like to do something else.

There are many different success and failure actions (such as ITEM_FETCH_SUCCESS or WIDGET_UPDATE_FAILURE), and adding a flag to all of them would be hard to remember to do when new ones are added.

Since all api requests go through a single function, that function COULD dispatch generic REQUEST_SUCCESS and REQUEST_FAILURE actions. But this would mean every response from the server would dispatch 2 actions (REQUEST_SUCCESS and ITEM_FETCH_SUCCESS). This is obviously not ideal since it would mean many more actions in my state history.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the generic `REQUEST_SUCCESS` and `REQUEST_FAILURE` actions are updating their own specific portions of the state-tree then it is fine to dispatch them as distinct actions. Doing this does not necessarily imply the pollution of your state history but can simply be a *better description* of the app's intentions.

- `ITEM_FETCH_SUCCESS`: Change state for `item`
- `REQUEST_SUCCESS`: Change state for `request`
- `WIDGET_UPDATE_FAILURE`: Change state for `widget`
- `REQUEST_FAILURE`: Change state for `request`

You can see that whilst the actions are intimately related, they are not necessarily the same thing as they change different parts of the state tree.

Accepting this, the question is: How best to implement the action-pairs so that adding new actions does not mean remembering to add its corresponding `REQUEST_*` partner?

I would consider applying a simple redux middleware component. This could intercept the return from your api and dispatch the appropriate `REQUEST_*` action automatically.

Here is an example from some live code. This middleware intercepts a `disconnect` event raised by a websocket and automatically dispatches a custom action as a result. It at least shows the principle:

```
//Dispatch a disconnect action when the websocket disconnects
//This is the custom action provided by the middleware

import io from 'socket.io-client'
import { actions } from './action'

const websocket = ({ websocketUrl }) => store => {
  const socket = io(websocketUrl)
  socket.on('disconnect', () => store.dispatch(actions.disconnect()))
}

export default websocket
```

---

```
//Apply the custom middleware via the redux createStore function
//Also include the thunk middleware because it is useful

import { applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import websocket from './middleware'

function websocketize (opts) {
  return createStore => (reducers, initial, enhancer) => {
    const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, websocket(opts))
    return createStore(reducers, initial, middleware)
  }
}

export default websocketize
```

---

```
// Create the top-level redux store passing in the custom middleware enhancer

const opts = {websocketUrl: env.WEBSOCKET_URL}
const store = createStore(reducers, websocketize(opts))
```

Comment: i'm not sure i agree on the distinct reducers need distinct actions part. For example, if i have an app_loaded action dispatched on startup, and multiple reducers needed to initialize their state based on that app_load data, i wouldn't want to dispatch an action for each reducer when i could just have all of them listen to the one app_loaded action. 

The problem here seems to be that i want multiple reducers to listen to multiple actions, unlike the init example. where multiple reducers listen to one action.

Comment: It might seem simpler to keep actions separated for each reducers, but I believe that a redux auther Dan Abramov said, this is not how redux is necessarily intended to be used. A single action could be used across many reducers especially in the case that you have data that has been normalized/denormalized.

Comment: I agree, it is perfectly fine to have the same action being interpreted differently in different reducers. It is also perfectly fine to have different actions for different changes to the state. This latter is not 'pollution' per se, but can simply be a _better description_ of the app's intentions. I have edited the intro to make this clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**This implementation keeps everything inside your reducers as opposed to having logic outside in an interception(middleware). Both ways are valid.**

Try a **sub-reducer** pattern. I usually feel gross when I see it used(because it is usually used wrong), but your situation sounds perfect.

1. Extract duplicate functionality out of your reducers to one single
   sub-reducer.
2. Then pass that reducer as a function to all others that need it.
3. Then pass the action and state onto the sub-reducer.
4. The sub-reducer does it's thing and returns that slice of state to
   your parent reducer to allow you to do whatever you want with it
   there (ie return it, mutate some more, some logic).

[Also if you are tired of worrying about typing out "all the stuff" for async then I highly recommend you try out redux-crud.js](https://github.com/Versent/redux-crud)

It also is possible and a simple way to do that would be to give every action to one reducer and let it do that common mutation, in a single case:

```
case actionOne
     actionTwo 
     actionThree
     actionFour: { 
       //do common stuff here
     }
```

. But you said it is not duplicated, it is similar, which means your case becomes complicated by branching logic. I also don't recommend this. Keep cases simple so you can easily catch invalid mutations. **This should be a super power of redux that it is easy to catch mutation errors.** And for this reason and many others I don't recommend normalizing data in the front end.

Comment: there's isn't really any duplicate functionality though. the itemsReducer might set the list of items in the state when a itemsFetchSuccessful action is dispatched. The reducer that needs to know about all different successes and failures keeps a global state though. It's not concerned with the list of items that comes back .So I don't think a piece of the state could be repeated.

Comment: my bad. duplicated or common functionallity... potatoes XD, either way this should still work for the situation.

Comment: but if you have a sub reducer used from a bunch of other reducer, wouldn't each one maintain its own piece of state? All of the pieces would look similar to the others, but each would only update its own copy of the data. I want to have all of them update a shared set of data.

Comment: Having EVERY reducer do mutations every time an action fires off seems like a bad idea. So what you describe is one action fire off and EVERY reducer will mutate state. This would be incredibly slow for large applications. That is the problem with normalization of data, you get great read speeds, but your write speeds go down the toilet.

Comment: It is possible and a simple way to do that would be to give every action to every reducer and let it do that common mutation, in a single case: "case actionOne actionTwo actionThree: { do stuff here}. But you said it is not duplicated, it is similar, which means your case becomes complicated by branching logic. I also don't recommend this. Keep cases simple so you can easily catch invalid mutations.